# PHP: Add some milliseconds to a date() with strtotime()

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to add just 500ms to a specific date. To add, for example, 1 day to a date, I know I can write this:

```
$tomorrow = date("d-m-Y",strtotime("+1 day"));
```

To add 500 milliseconds to a date, instead, I tried with

```
strotime("+500 milliseconds",date(...
```

but it's not working, date becomes 00-00 etc., or sometimes it remains the same.

Thanks for any help,
Alberto

Comment: PHP date  & time function operate to 1 second accuracy. They don't understand milliseconds.

Comment: There's no way to add less that a second to a date format?

Comment: @AlbertoZanatta That's what he just said...  I don't understand why people ask for help, get an answer, and then question the validity of that answer when they should really ask a different question... such as "how can I manipulate timestamps with millisecond accuracy in PHP"

Comment: @Brad, I've forgot to write a "So" at the beginning of my re-question :)
That's what I'm looking for, I've asked this because I need a way to work with milliseconds. If I transform my date in unix date (seconds since january 1970) I can't modify milliseconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to work with milliseconds, you can check out [`microtime()`](http://php.net/microtime).

To advance the current time by 500 milliseconds ahead, you can use:

```
microtime(true) + 0.5
```